# C - Infinitive loop when using for loop

Tags: c

Please tell me what wrong with my code :

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct rights_on_cmd{
        char *gtm_cmd; /*set ,zrite ,kill...*/
        char value; /*y or n*/
} ;
struct usr_rights{
        char *username;/*user name*/
        struct rights_on_cmd rights[]; /*list gtm command & right on this command for user*/
};
struct rights_on_gbl{
        char *gbl_name;
        struct usr_rights user_list[]; /*list users have and specific right on global*/
};

int main(){
        int i ;
        struct rights_on_gbl gbl_list[2];
        for(i = 0;i <= 2; i = i + 1){
                struct rights_on_gbl gbl;
                char gbl_name[20];
                printf("Input global variable name: ");
                scanf("%s",&gbl_name);
                int j;

                gbl.gbl_name = gbl_name;
                printf("******Setting for global : %s\n",gbl_name);
                for(j = 0;j <= 2 ; j = j + 1) {

                        char username[20];
                        struct usr_rights user;
                        char *set,kill,zwrite;
                        struct rights_on_cmd set_cmd ,kill_cmd,zwrite_cmd;

                        printf("Input username: ");
                        scanf("%s",&username);                         
                        printf("Does user %s have permission on set: [y/n] ",username);
                        scanf("%s",&set);
                        set_cmd.gtm_cmd = "set";
                        set_cmd.value = set;
                        user.rights[0] = set_cmd;
                        printf("Does user %s have permission on kill: [y/n] ",username);
                        scanf("%s",&kill);
                        kill_cmd.gtm_cmd = "kill";
                        kill_cmd.value = kill;
                        user.rights[1] = kill_cmd;
                        printf("Does user %s have permission on zwrite: [y/n] ",username);
                        scanf("%s",&zwrite);
                        zwrite_cmd.gtm_cmd = "zwrite";
                        zwrite_cmd.value = zwrite;
                        user.rights[2] = zwrite_cmd;
                        user.username = username;      
                        gbl.user_list[j] = user;

                };
                gbl_list[i] = gbl;

        };
        int f ;

        for(f = 0; f < 2 ; f++){
                printf("%s",gbl_list[f].gbl_name);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It's get infinitive loop at :

```
for(j = 0;j <= 2 ; j = j + 1) { 
   ....
}
```

I can not found the reason why the `j` index not increase after each loop

Thanks,

//Update : this comment just for bypass adding code more than comment

Comment: Please add the relevant code in the body of your question.

Comment: Your loop is correct, show the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I update rest of code

Comment: There are some bugs. You should mention the array size in the structure defintion on line 9 and 13. Rest are pointed out in answers. Also since `set,kill,zwrite` are supposed to be only `y/n` hence go for `char set,kill,zwrite ;` instead of pointers.

Comment: To me its looks as if you did not (yet) learned/understood how C-"strings" work, that those are `char`-**arrays** carrying a trailing `0`-terminator.

Comment: @alk ,You are right ,I'm come from Java to C ,many things is different to me :)

Comment: This `user.username = username;` probably does not do what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are accessing an uninitialized arrays rights[] and user_list[]; 
use malloc to allocate memory for them, or define the boundaries. 
for examle:

```
struct usr_rights{
    char *username;/*user name*/
    struct rights_on_cmd rights[3]; /* << HERE */
};
struct rights_on_gbl{
    char *gbl_name;
    struct usr_rights user_list[3]; /* << and HERE*/
};
```

Comment: this solves the main problem, but still errors exists in the code you submited.

Comment: Thanks ,this fix my problem about loop infinitive :) ,you right ,now the loop infinitive occurred at outside loop : `for(i = 0;i <= 2; i = i + 1){ `

Comment: where exactly. please post your modified with comments.

Comment: Thanks , I fixed it :D

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. All these

   ```
   scanf("%s",&gbl_name);
   scanf("%s",&username);  
   scanf("%s",&set);
   scanf("%s",&kill);
   scanf("%s",&zwrite);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   scanf("%s", gbl_name);
   scanf("%s", username);  
   scanf(" %c", &set);
   scanf(" %c", &kill);
   scanf(" %c", &zwrite); /* The reason for using %c is explaned below */
   ```

   because `%s` in the `scanf` expects a `char*`, not a `char(*)[20]` or a `char**`.
2. You have

   ```
   char *set,kill,zwrite;
   ```

   which declares a `char*` `set` and two `char`s `kill` and `zwrite`. It should be something like

   ```
   char set, kill, zwrite;
   ```

   because you want to input characters, not strings. That's why the last three `scanf`s in problem #1 use a `%c`.

Comment: Thanks ,after fixed all issues which you told me ,have no warning showing ,but maybe it not work as I expect ,I can not input after using %c

Comment: There are a few more problems which I've not mentioned like scope of those `char` arrays( Fix by moving `char gbl_name[20];` and `char username[20];` before `for(i = 0;i <= 2; i = i + 1){`) and you using invalid memory locations. I'm a bit busy now. You can wait for more answers or post a new question explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have buffer over flow in parts of your code, the behavior of you program yet is unpredictable.

check the boundaries of these

```
user.rights[0] = set_cmd;
user.rights[1] = kill_cmd;
user.rights[2] = zwrite_cmd;
gbl.user_list[j] = user;
```